# Are Apple maps for iPhone broken in SE Asia in 2018?

Tags: iphone, ios, maps

I have iOS 11.2.2 and have not used Apple maps in a long time. I’m seeing a blank map with a grid on iPhone, but no actual map layer or tiles ever loading when zoomed in.

**How do I fix broken empty Apple maps in 2018?**

Map tiles load at the country or globe level, but when zooming in, they disappear. I see buildings layer overlay for landmarks, but no actual streets or placemarks. Directions are working.

I tried reinstalling the Maps app from the App Store but no success.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd suspect some kind of routing issue - firewall or even DNS. I can see the area around there just fine, though I'm round the other side of the world.

Comment: I agree with @Tetsujin.  I'm in the US and I can see all the streets and buildings surrounding your screenshot location.  It's not a Maps issue.

Comment: I had another person in US confirm he's seeing just the grid, even around him in California.

Comment: Is he also on an outdated iOS?